# Reading Sharepoint List in SPFx - ForEach not working

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-framework, odata

I have no idea how to read Sharepoint List Data in SPFx one by one.

JavaSript console returns me an error: *Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: item.forEach is not a function.*

```
  private ReadAllCountries(): void {
    var sel = <HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementById("visitstate");
    this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TravelRequests_Countries')/items?$orderby=Title%20desc&$select=Title`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
    .then((res: HttpClientResponse): Promise<any> => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((item: any): void => {
      console.log(item)

      var a: number = 0;
      item.forEach(prd => {
        var opt = <HTMLOptionElement>document.createElement("option");
        opt.value = `${item[a].Title}`;
        opt.text = `${item[a].Title}`;
        sel.add(opt, sel.options[a]);
        a++;
      });

    }, (error: any): void => {
      console.log('Loading user details failed with error: ' + error);
    });
  }
```

My  goal is to be able read each row in result one by one. Here for example only Title values.

Current output with console.log(item) is:

[image]

Thank you so much for your help or any comment,

Michal

Comment: Isn't that because the array is under `value` property? Try `item.value.forEach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array of your items is inside json.value object.

```
private ReadAllCountries(): void {
    var sel = <HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementById("visitstate");
    this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TravelRequests_Countries')/items?$orderby=Title%20desc&$select=Title`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
    .then((res: HttpClientResponse): Promise<any> => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((item: any): void => {
      console.log(item)

      var a: number = 0;
      item.value.forEach(prd => {
        var opt = <HTMLOptionElement>document.createElement("option");
        opt.value = `${item[a].Title}`;
        opt.text = `${item[a].Title}`;
        sel.add(opt, sel.options[a]);
        a++;
      });

    }, (error: any): void => {
      console.log('Loading user details failed with error: ' + error);
    });
  }
```

hope this helps..happy coding..!!1

Comment: It's working now. I just made little modiffication of your code in filling opt.value and opt.text - needed to put `${item.value[a].Title}`. Thank you so much for your tip